# When can I cast Eternal Scourge from exile?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Eternal Scourge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEternal%20Scourge%5d) is exiled. Can I cast Eternal Scourge from exile anytime I wish, or is the only opportunity to cast Eternal Scourge from exile during my main phase/s?

Answer (score 9):

**You can only cast [Eternal Scourge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=414296) from exile during your pre-combat or post-combat main phases if the stack is empty.** (eg. with the same timing restrictions as casting it normally)

This is addressed specifically in [Eternal Scourge's rulings](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=414296):

> **7/13/2016:** You must follow the normal timing permissions and restrictions and pay its cost to cast Eternal Scourge from exile.

As for what "*normal timing permissions and restrictions*" means, look to the comprehensive rules for casting a creature spell:

> **302.1.** A player who has priority may cast a creature card from his or her hand during a main phase of his or her turn when the stack is empty. Casting a creature as a spell uses the stack. (See rule 601, “Casting Spells.”)

The ability text on Eternal Scourge just lets you substitute "*from his or her hand*" with "*from exile*", but nothing else about casting creatures changes.

<sup>As a side note, if you have any spells that would modify when you are able to cast creature spells (for example, [Aluren](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397389)) unless they specify "*cast from your hand*" those modifications would apply to Eternal Scourge as well.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

It only changes from where it can be cast, not when it can be cast.

You can only cast spells when you instructed to cast them. You are optionally instructed to cast non-instant spells during a main phase on your turn when the stack is empty and you have priority.

> 302.1. A player who has priority may cast a creature card from his or her hand during a main phase of his or her turn when the stack is empty. [...]

[Eternal Scourge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEternal%20Scourge%5d)'s ability simply modifies this rule to make it a valid candidate for casting if it's in Exile. It doesn't change when you can cast a spell.

> Ruling from 7/13/2016: You must follow the normal timing permissions and restrictions and pay its cost to cast Eternal Scourge from exile.

Note that [Teferi, Mage of Zhalfir](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeferi%2c%20Mage%20of%20Zhalfir%5d) would allow you to cast Eternal Scourge "as an instant".

Comment: You know, I can't find the rule that states you can only cast spells from your hand to begin with...

Comment: The rules that cover this are in the Card Types subsection. For example, rule 301.1 says "A player who has priority may cast an artifact card **from his or her hand** during a main phase of his or her turn when the stack is empty." There are similar rules for each other card type. Cards can only be cast from another zone when another rule or ability explicitly allows it.

Comment: @steenbergh I figured I would add the relevant rule for completeness sake to my answer, but I can understand keeping things brief.

Comment: @murgatroid99, Adjusted answer.